# Как найти разницу времени в секундах в списке?

Tags: python-3.x, list, время, список, datetime

Есть список со временем

```py
time = ['08:53:47', '08:53:50', '08:53:52', '08:53:55', '08:53:56']
```

Нужно найти разницу между этим временем в секундах:

```
00:00:03
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:01
```

Цепочка идеи: 
преобразовать строчное время, найти разницу, внести разницу в новый список. Только вот как это реализовать у меня, как у новичка, нет возможности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [135]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [136]: times = ['08:53:47', '08:53:50', '08:53:52', '08:53:55', '08:53:56']

In [137]: def to_time(s, fmt="%H:%M:%S"):
     ...:     return DT.strptime(s, fmt)
     ...:

In [138]: [to_time(times[i]) - to_time(times[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(times))]
Out[138]:
[datetime.timedelta(0, 3),
 datetime.timedelta(0, 2),
 datetime.timedelta(0, 3),
 datetime.timedelta(0, 1)]
```

в виде строк:

```
In [141]: [str(to_time(times[i]) - to_time(times[i-1])) for i in range(1, len(times))]
Out[141]: ['0:00:03', '0:00:02', '0:00:03', '0:00:01']
```